# Dynamic dependent form select inputs

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm building a custom dependent dropdown form with 2 select inputs.

I've managed to build the form inputs and update them accordingly, but I'm not able to get the dependent select's value in the submit hook.

I think this happens because I changed (via `AjaxResponse()/ReplaceCommand`) the `$form` in the AJAX callback, and as such, the second input values aren't updated in the `$form_state`.

My problem is that I have no simple way of knowing which options will be available either in the first-level select nor in the dependent select, since they come from a 3rd-party API.

Is there any way I can trigger the update of the `#options` in the dependent select, **without** having to render the nested dropdown and changing the `$form` so that the nested values are available in the `submit` hook?

Or, alternatively, is there anyway I can update the `$form_state` so that it knows the newly added `#options` of the second select?

Comment: $form is rebuilt in each ajax request before your ajax callback is even invoked. And then in your callback you are only allowed to use form elements from $form, because otherwise the form element is not processed and can't be submitted.

Comment: @4k4 thanks for your feedback, but I'm not sure what you mean. My dependent select element already exists in the form when it is first built, it just doesn't have the `#options` populated. After I populate them in the AJAX callback, they show up in the markup, but aren't available in the submit hook to be processed. Can you suggest how to handle this?

Comment: You populate the options in the form rebuild. The form build function knows that it is rebuilding when $form_state is filled with user input, which it is not on the first build.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with your remarks. Can you point me to some documentation regarding this?

Comment: See the topic "The Big Idea" in https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7

Comment: @4k4 I got it working with your help and those docs, thank you! If you want to create an answer based on this, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted. I'll write my own though, so I can clear up my misconceptions and hopefully help someone else.

Comment: Please go ahead with your answer, sure this will help a lot of people, because ajax callbacks are a bit counterintuitive. I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

With @4k4's help I managed to find the root cause of my issue and fix it.

I was wrongfully assuming that the `$form` elements could be somehow modified in an AJAX call to produce my desired effect.

While it is true that the elements could be modified and re-rendered in an AJAX response, that is not the correct way to alter a form after an AJAX call.

The 2 main things to know are:

- forms are **rebuilt** everytime an AJAX call is made (when it is declared in the `#ajax` array of the form element triggering the call)
- the AJAX function being called should (ideally) only return the element suffering modifications. It **cannot** modify the `$form` in any way, otherwise those modification will either be lost when it is rebuilt, or trigger the `An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.` message.

This being said, the general flow for this should be:

- create the `buildForm` function with code that builds both your select elements. Wrap in a conditional clause code that tests if the parent select was already changed or not. This will be used to determine if the nested select should be populated or not;
- set an `#ajax` property in the parent select element of the form, referring a callback to be used;
- define the callback to return only the element which needs to change in the form, ie, the nested select;
- when Drupal tries to rebuild the form, your parent select will already have a value that can be used in the above mentioned test-clause to allow for population of the nested callback.

@4k4's suggested documentation was difficult for me to find, but clear enough to follow trough once found - link [here](http://drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7). (Even though it is for Drupal 7, in Drupal 8 it functioned exactly the same way).