# Ajax dependent drop down not working on form rebuild

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a drupal custom form with two ajax dependent dropdown fields and five normal text fields. on form submit, all things are working fine except validation of form fields. when I put validations on form fields with validate function is working but ajax fields are losing their values. where is the exact problem? I am stuck here.(Using Drupal 8.6.10)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: this might be connected https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251018/dynamic-dependent-form-select-inputs

Comment: I have already used the flow given by Joum but during validation how should I avoid resetting the ajax field values?